# Passing Tuple to a function via apply

Tags: pandas, function, tuples

I am trying to run below function which takes two points..

```
point A=(2,3)
point B=(4,5

def Somefunc(pointA, point B):
     x= pointA[0] + pointB[1]
     
  return x
```

Now, when in try to create a separate column based on this fucntion, it is throwing me errors like `cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>`, so I tried this

```
df['T']=df.apply(Somefunc((df['A'].apply(lambda x: float(x)),df['B'].apply(lambda x: float(x))),\
                 (df['C'].apply(lambda x: float(x)),df['D'].apply(lambda x: float(x)))),axis=0))
```

Sample dataframe below;

```
A B C D
1 2 3 5
2 4 7 8
4 7 9 0
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try doing the float conversion in your function `return float(x)` and take it off when you're applying your lambda function

Comment: Why is there so many apply functions nested together this is gonna give me nightmares. What do you want your result to look like?

Comment: Apologies but I tried different ways but can seem to get to the output.. result will be a new column based on the result of function.. the problem is function ask for a point A but in actual it is the combination of two seperate columns point A=(A,B) similarly point B=(C,D)

Comment: @ShahrukhKhalidi No worries, I edited the original answer now that I now what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best guess I can make as to what you're trying to do:

```
df['T']=df.apply(lambda row: [(row['A'],row['B']),(row['C'],row['D'])],axis=1)
```

**Edit:** to apply your function;

```
df['T'] = df.apply(lambda row: SomeFunc((row['A'],row['B']),(row['C'],row['D'])),axis=1)
```

that being said, the same result can be achieved much quicker and idiomatically like so:

```
>>> df
   A  B  C  D
0  2  7  3  3
1  3  1  5  7
2  2  0  6  2
3  3  9  5  9
4  0  2  3  7
>>> df['T']=df.apply(tuple,axis=1)
>>> df
   A  B  C  D             T
0  2  7  3  3  (2, 7, 3, 3)
1  3  1  5  7  (3, 1, 5, 7)
2  2  0  6  2  (2, 0, 6, 2)
3  3  9  5  9  (3, 9, 5, 9)
4  0  2  3  7  (0, 2, 3, 7)
```

Comment: @ShahrukhKhalidi no worries! FYI, applying row-wise: axis=1, column-wise: axis=0